# String starts with in Google Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am working on a data converting script for some elections we are doing. The first part changes all the names to upper case, and this part of the script works fine. However, I have a problem with the second part of the script. Some IDs will have an S, S123456, and some will not have an S, 123456. For my purposes I need all IDs to have no s at the beginning. When I run this script in Google it returns

> TypeError: Cannot find function startsWith in object S123456.

Any ideas?

```js
function convertResponseData(){
  var resultsInformation = SpreadsheetApp.openById('MySheetID').getSheetByName('Election Responses');
  var resultsDataRange = resultsInformation.getRange(1, 1, 2500, 6);
  var resultsData = resultsDataRange.getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < resultsData.length; i++) {
    var row = resultsData[i];
    var resultsStudentNameLower = row[1];
    var resultsStudentID = row[2]
    var studentNameUpper = resultsStudentNameLower.toUpperCase()
    resultsInformation.getRange(i+1, 2).setValue(studentNameUpper)
    if (var n = resultsStudentID.startsWith("S")){
      var resultsStudentIDNoS = resultsStudentID.substring(1,20);
      resultsInformation.getRange(i+1, 3).setValue(resultsStudentIDNoS)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `Cannot find function startsWith` - which browser are you using? And, is `resultsStudentID` always a string? perhaps you need to check like so `if (resultsStudentID.startsWith && resultsStudentID.startsWith("S")){` - you can remove the `var n =` too, because you never use that value

Comment: alternatively, `if (resultsStudentID.toString().startsWith("S")){` - as long as your browser isn't Internet Exploder

Comment: I am using Google Chrome and I tried `if (resultsStudentID.toString().startsWith("S")){` and it gave me the same error. @JaromandaX

Comment: odd ... what is `console.log(typeof resultsStudentID)`

Comment: The log returned [17-04-04 20:59:53:932 EDT] string @JaromandaX

Comment: the error message you claim `Cannot find function startsWith in object S123456` doesn't make sense with respect to the code you posted ... you only ever `resultsStudentID.startsWith` - I take it the location of the error is **not** the line you use `.startsWith` on - perhaps you should look at the stack trace to see which line of code is causing the error

Answer (score 36):

`startsWith()` is not supported in google scripts. Instead, you can use

```
resultsStudentID.indexOf("S") == 0
```

To check if the string start starts with "S"

```
function convertResponseData(){
  var resultsInformation = SpreadsheetApp.openById('MySheetID').getSheetByName('Election Responses');
  var resultsDataRange = resultsInformation.getRange(1, 1, 2500, 6);
  var resultsData = resultsDataRange.getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < resultsData.length; i++) {
    var row = resultsData[i];
    var resultsStudentNameLower = row[1];
    var resultsStudentID = row[2]
    var studentNameUpper = resultsStudentNameLower.toUpperCase()
    resultsInformation.getRange(i+1, 2).setValue(studentNameUpper)
    if (resultsStudentID.indexOf("S") == 0 ){
      var resultsStudentIDNoS = resultsStudentID.substring(1,20);  //You also do this resultsStudentID.substring(1) to get a substring from index 1 to end. 
      resultsInformation.getRange(i+1, 3).setValue(resultsStudentIDNoS)
    }
  }
}
```

Hope that helps

Comment: This is the correct answer. Seems that the author of the question forgot about this topic, but this shoud be marked as the valid solution for this problem

Answer (score 5):

### Update 2020:

**You can now use Modern ECMAScript syntax thanks to [V8 Runtime](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/v8-runtime)**.

You can use [startsWith()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith):

```
function myFunction() {
  let str = 'Something';
  console.log(str.startsWith("S")); // returns true
}
```

Comment: Also works for more than 1 character... `if (rangeVals[row][0].startsWith("10%")) {`

Comment: Yet it still does not work with non-latin characters (at least Cyrillic ones), so you have to transliterate your strings to latin before comparing.