# Javascript - TypeError: Cannot find function startsWith in object

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to write a custom function in Google Sheets to format some phone numbers.

Each cell contains numbers like this:

- 434268713
- 800270963
- 300303544
- 741244611

And I want to write a formula that outputs them like this:

- Anything that starts with 4: 434268713 -> 0434 268 713
- Anything that starts with 8: 800270963 -> 1800 270 965
- Anything that starts with 3: 300303544 -> 1300 303 544
- Anything that starts with 7: 741244611 -> (07) 4124 4611

I have been writing this function, but Google Sheets gives me an error:

"TypeError: Cannot find function startsWith in object 800270963. (line 2)."

```
function D7PHONE(phone) {
  if (phone.startsWith(4)) {
    return "0" + str.substring(0, 2) + " " + str.substring(3, 5) + " " + str.substring(6, 8);
  } else if (phone.startsWith(8)) {
    return "1" + str.substring(0, 2) + " " + str.substring(3, 5) + " " + str.substring(6, 8);
  } else if (phone.startsWith(3)) {
    return "1" + str.substring(0, 2) + " " + str.substring(3, 5) + " " + str.substring(6, 8);
  } else if (phone.startsWith(7)) {
    return "(0" + str.substring(0, 1) + ") " + str.substring(3, 5) + " " + str.substring(6, 8);
  }
}
```

Comment: where is your `startsWith` function ?

Comment: @KarmaBlackshaw it's part of the `String` prototype. But I have a feeling that these are not strings but objects, and that's the issue.

Comment: I have been Googling try and build this, and I thought I could just use it inside an IF statement. Where else am I supposed to put it?

Comment: @BenTurner I'm not too familiar with scripting in Sheets but what's the `typeof(phone)`?

Comment: @rb612 its a number :)

Comment: try `phone = phone.toString()`

Comment: @KarmaBlackshaw same error

Comment: can you try `console.log(phone)` ?

Comment: Looks like reason is because sheets doesn't support [startsWith](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43220573/3813411).

Comment: Use a polyfill: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith

Answer (score 1):

As @rb612 pointed out Sheets does not support `startsWith()` so I made a work around using regex.

```
function D7PHONE(phone) {
  phone = phone.toString();
  if (/^4/.test(phone)) {
    return "0" + phone.substring(0, 3) + " " + phone.substring(3, 6) + " " + phone.substring(6, 9);
  } else if (/^8/.test(phone)) {
    return "1" + phone.substring(0, 3) + " " + phone.substring(3, 6) + " " + phone.substring(6, 9);
  } else if (/^3/.test(phone)) {
    return "1" + phone.substring(0, 3) + " " + phone.substring(3, 6) + " " + phone.substring(6, 9);
  } else if (/^7/.test(phone)) {
    return "(0" + phone.substring(0, 1) + ") " + phone.substring(1, 5) + " " + phone.substring(5, 9);
  }
}
```